# accept remote domain get/post request

Tags: php, apache

I am working on a linux server that doesn't accept requests(get/post) remote domains. Like, if I use a form on another domain and post that to a script on this server, it isn't processing it. I like to know what options I will have to enable to get this done so that it accepts remote requests please? is it something in the php.ini?

Regards

Comment: Such a behavour is most probably configured through the webserver. I would use mod_rewrite with apache if i'd had to block posts from other domains, not php.

Comment: how are you get/post it? are you using ajax?

Comment: yes, I am requesting get/post using ajax.

Comment: @Spliffster, server is dedicated, so i have no problem if i need to change anything. Just need to figure out what is responsible for this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the webserver blocks the posts via referrer, you would need to find a way to send a referrer from your web site. Sending the post to a script first and from there to your site would give you the possibility to fake the referrer request header.

The following code of an example php proxy is borrowed from here: http://snipplr.com/view/16058/php-url-proxy/

```
<?php
// PHP Proxy
// Responds to both HTTP GET and POST requests
//
// Author: Abdul Qabiz
// March 31st, 2006
//

// Get the url of to be proxied
// Is it a POST or a GET?
$url = ($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : $_GET['url'];
$headers = ($_POST['headers']) ? $_POST['headers'] : $_GET['headers'];
$mimeType =($_POST['mimeType']) ? $_POST['mimeType'] : $_GET['mimeType'];


//Start the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);

// If it's a POST, put the POST data in the body
if ($_POST['url']) {
$postvars = '';
while ($element = current($_POST)) {
$postvars .= key($_POST).'='.$element.'&';
next($_POST);
}
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
}

// Don't return HTTP headers. Do return the contents of the call
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, ($headers == "true") ? true : false);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Make the call
$response = curl_exec($session);

// NOTE: HERE YOU WILL OVERRIDE THE REFERRER REQUEST HEADER
if ($mimeType != "")
{
// The web service returns XML. Set the Content-Type appropriately
header("Content-Type: ".$mimeType);
}

echo $response;

curl_close($session);

?>
```